# Facebook Login doesn't work in ios app after the app has been released

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps

I've developed an iOS app that shares a photo on Facebook; I've created an app on Facebook developer portal and before the iOS app has been released sharing works fine. But after app store release when I (and all users) try to login to Facebook before sharing the Facebook app opens and goes back to my app, but login hasn't been set. How can I make it work?

Comment: check the Bundle identifier used in Development mode and Production mode... is both are same?

Comment: Checkout for the Bundle I.D you have registered in the F.B App and also checkout whether it's of having the right permissions to proceed, i.e E-mail, name and Sharing_permission's.